# Trying to return Bool based on counts of items in a list without using any more than once

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to make an application to use as a game aid. This game has a pool of items, each with a set of resources required to craft it (recipe). Each resource is unique, but most can be used as a base type i.e. "Fur" can be used as "Fur" OR as a basic "Hide" resource. Essentially I'm trying to return whether I have enough resources in inventory to craft a recipe.

Ideally, given the following resources

```
Id,Name,Bone,Hide,Organ
1, Monster Bone, true, false, false
2, Monster Hide, false, true, false
3, Monster Organ, false, false, true
4, Resource XXXX, true, false, false
```

and a 'recipe' with the following info

```
Bone = 2 //number of bone needed
Hide = 0
Organ = 0
UniqueResourceId = 4 //Which unique resource I'd need
UniqueResourceCount = 1 //How many of the unique resource I need
```

I would be able to return a true/false based on my inventory, so an inventory of

```
Id, ResourceId
1,1 //basic bone
2,2 //basic hide
3,2 //another basic hide
4,4 //Resource X
```

would return false, because after using 'Resource X' I only have one bone left, where

```
Id, ResourceId
1,1 //basic bone
2,2 //basic hide
3,2 //another basic hide
4,4 //Resource X
5,1 //second basic bone
```

or

```
Id, ResourceId
1,1 //basic bone
2,2 //basic hide
3,2 //another basic hide
4,4 //Resource X
5,4 //second Resource X
```

would return true, because I have enough resources that can be used as bone after using the first 'Resource X'

**Edit to add some more detail**

Regarding resources

Resources may count as multiple types of base resources ie Resource Y could count as both a bone and hide basic resource

No resource should be used more than one time ie Given Resource Y above you could use that as Resource Y (the unique resource) OR Bone OR Hide

This also makes things more difficult in a case where you have the following recipe

```
Bone = 2
Hide = 0
Organ = 1
```

and the following resources

```
2x Resource Y (assume this can be bone/hide)
1x Resource Z (assume this can be bone/hide/organ)
```

You have to ensure that the resources are used correctly, since only one cane be used as Organ while all could be used as bone. Haven't figured this bit out yet.

**End Edit**

I tried some stuff with Hashsets and adding resources as they are used, but I feel like once I have to start checking for 8 different 'base' resource types  and up to 5 unique resources per recipe this becomes a bottleneck. There are around 150 craftable items as of now with more to come, and I'd like this to be run against all recipes when checked, so if there is a better/faster way I'm all ears.

FWIW, here is one of my trials with hashset

```
public static bool AltSimpleCraftabilityTest()
{
    Recipe r = new Recipe
    {
        Bone = 2,
        FirstUniqueResourceId = 5,
        FirstUniqueResourceCount = 1
    };

    List<InventoriedResource> ir = da.GetAvailableResources();

    HashSet<InventoriedResource> UsedResources = new HashSet<InventoriedResource>();

    UsedResources.Add(ir.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Resource.Id == r.FirstUniqueResourceId));

    UsedResources.UnionWith(ir.Where(x => x.Resource.Bone == true).Take(r.Bone));

    return UsedResources.Count == r.Bone + r.FirstUniqueResourceCount;
}
```

I know its ugly but I was just experimenting some, though I'm sure you can see how extending this would become...unwieldy.

Comment: And you should remove the persistence part at all - it is just a lot of noise. Just show us the Resource type and the Recipe type. For the Resource type having Bone, Hide, Organ use an enum marked as Flags

Comment: Detail added. I'm unsure what you mean by the "persistence" bit

Comment: Remove everything which refers to your tables. It does not matter for this question if you store your data in memory, in database or in a simple textfile. It is just noise

Comment: Alright I removed the  data structure info

Comment: I wrote some code I would have used for this kind of question see at [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/64sfYZ) - Now it would be easy to copy/paste the code and made an implementation for `CanCraft` extension method

Comment: I appreciate the response. I've thought about dictionaries before but I wasn't sure of the best way to iterate through them to test. I'm curious how you would approach a test like that, is there some better way than just iterating through and adding the used resources to a Hashset or some such?

Comment: With this requirements I would say we need a [Backtracking algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). So it is a little bit more complicated than just iterating and using a hashset

Comment: I'll have to read up on that, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I have implemented a Backtracking algorithm for CanCraft. Have a look at [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jimSbr)

Comment: Awesome, this seems to fit the bill. Once I get this integrated and all the data entered I can do some testing around performance. Thanks again

Comment: There was a small bug caused by the ResourceKind enum - the fixed [code is here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DtSxgR)